# What factors should I consider when pricing commercial use licenses for digital products that aren't software?

Tags: contracts, pay-rate, price, copyright, licensing

Most of the licensing questions I see on here are about software-type products. I'm asking about products such as pre-made templates, worksheets, planners, and illustrations. In other words, creative elements or templates.

In my research, I've seen people offer varying prices based on number of sales, how many products it can be included in, if explicit credit is required, etc. I'm also wondering if there should be a difference between immutable products (e.g., an illustration or worksheet as-is) or mutable products (e.g., the full template from Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign, etc.).

I know pricing is always a difficult question, but I'm wondering how more experienced freelancers approach this topic. Personally, I already sell direct to customer items, but the next logical step in my business is to create licenses for larger commercial customers. I'm already getting requests and want to respond professionally.